# How to convert decimal to base 12 ?? Using Debug

Tags: debugging, assembly

I don't know how to start this program. Can anyone help me or teach me how to start with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly Conversion any base to any base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101852/assembly-conversion-any-base-to-any-base)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system